# Can't get IDentityDbContext derived class to work: The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have the following ApplicationDbContext class:

```
using EsportshubApi.Models.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EsportshubApi.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Account>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext() {}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

Account class looks like so:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace EsportshubApi.Models.Entities
{
    public class Account : IdentityUser
    {
        private Account() { }

        public static AccountBuilder Builder()
        {
            return new AccountBuilder(new Account());
        }

        public string AccountId { get; set; }
        public Guid AccountGuid { get; set; }
        public string Salt { get; set; }
        public bool Verified { get; set; }
        public string Checksum { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    }

}
```

In my Startup.cs inside of the method ConfigureServices i run:

```
            services.AddIdentity<Account, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            app.UseIdentity();
```

And inside of the Startup.cs Configure method i run:

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
         {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            using (var serviceScope =    app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<EsportshubContext>().Database.Migrate();
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
                serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<EsportshubContext>().EnsureSeedData();
            }
        }

 app.UseIdentity();
```

And when running my application with a development environment, i get  this error:

```
The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

In my world IdentityUserLogin is a system class, and everything i do is "allowed" so it boggles me how this can ever give an error. I have read about this issue in similar posts, but usually they need to add the OnModelCreating base.OnModelCreating call, which i have. Does anyone have a suggestion??

Thanks.

Edit:

Even if i simplify it to this:

```
using EsportshubApi.Models.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


namespace EsportshubApi.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext() {}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().HasKey(iul => iul.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey(r => r.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
        }
    }


}
```

Where i just give it IdentityUser directly it doesn't work

Comment: I have not worked with ApplicationDbContext but that error means IdentityUserLogin does not have a property which is to be used for the primary key column. All entities must have a primary key. The error may also be because some other entity does not have primary key.

Comment: The applicationDbContext is just my own class that inherits from the IdentityDbContext.

Comment: Try this, It solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/40824620/7046796

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the failure is that the lack of `base.OnModelCreating()`, which is in the method `OnModelCreating`  called by the `dbcontext` class.

Answer (score 0):

Decorate AccountGuid (if this is your primary key) with Key attribute so EF knows this is a primary key as below:

```
[Key]
public Guid AccountGuid { get; set; }
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything unfortunately, i allready tried that with       public string AccountId { get; set; }, i also made my constructor public, that didn't help either. And i added some lines to my OnModelCreating aswell that set the keys on the model, but to no prevail :( and i have followed the IDentityDbContext all the way down its hierarchy, and everything looks fine, if i dont give a type to the IDentityUser it defaults to a string key, and basically gives that key on to all the other classes aswell like forexample IdentityUserLogin

Comment: hmm just curious if you comment out the Account class, do you still get the  same error?

Comment: If you see my update of the post , i now try to just give in IdentityUser directly into the IdentityDbContext, and it still gives the same error.,

Comment: Can you please comment out all of Account class and see what happens?  I want to know if the error is related to Account class or something else.

Comment: I would like to do that, but its a pretty big application, so it would ripple through it all, with a missing class,  would take a long time.  And as you can see in the code bit, i give the identityuser class directly into the identitydbcontext, so the application at that point has no idea that there is a class called Account. I am pretty sure that the solution is looking a bit like my OnModelCreating method, or maybe a custom class extending IdentityUserLogin class giving it a primary key.

Comment: ok we are getting closer. I just saw that. Now the question is what is IdentityUserLogin? This is what the error is complaining about

Comment: yeah. my application is opensourced at https://github.com/DenLilleMand/esportshubapi inside of src/restfulapi ... have to copy default.appsettings.json to appsettings.json ... give it a valid connection string. And then its able to be executed with "dotnet run --environment Development"

Comment: Its a Mysql database aswell, i was even thinking that it might be a bug with the MYSQL driver, since its complaining something about a primary key. i am so lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128548/discussion-between-codingyoshi-and-denlillemand).

Comment: Oh.. i tried on a MSSQL server now, and that doesn't work either. So at least i can exclude that.