# Integrate MVC Core Identity with other Database First Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity, database-first

I am using MVC Core with the default individual user authentication. 
I added FullName field to AspNetUsers Table and it is working fine. 
I need to create a relationship between my tables to the id field in the AspNetUsers table so I can get the fullname of the user.

I have no idea on how to create relationship in Entity framework, I tried to add the following in the ApplicationUser Class

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public mytable T { get; set; }
}
```

and

in mytable model, I added the following

`public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }`

unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

**The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined**

any idea?

Comment: do you use code first or db first?

Comment: @hasan I used database first, I made scaffolding, then I migrated the ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: you can use stackoverflow.com/a/20669370/3089009

Comment: that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The first issue solved by following link

https://forums.asp.net/post/6144294.aspx

the IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined also solved by

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40824620/7046796